# PyTesseract giving Bad result

Tags: python, ocr

I will write a code that takes the text from the image and I used Pytesseract for this, but it does not give proper results. I used a few more sources, but the result is still the same.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\tesseract\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

def ocr_core(img):
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

def get_grayscale(img):
    return cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


def remove_noise(img):
    return cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

def threshold(img):
    return cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

img = cv2.imread(r"/path/to/filename.jpg")
img = get_grayscale(img)
img = threshold(img)
img = remove_noise(img)

print(ocr_core(img))
```

How can fix this ?

pytesseract get text from image and image handling

Comment: "but it does not give proper results" - what exactly does this mean? What result do you think you should get, and why? What result do you actually get, and how is that different from what you expected?

Comment: That's what I meant when I said that it captures the texts, but most of the texts are wrong and nonsense, things that have nothing to do with the texts in the picture, and some of them give correct and wrong results.

Comment: Also, English is not my native language, my sentences may be wrong, I translate them using tranlate

Comment: We need to see specific examples in order to understand the problem.

Comment: ok I will provide more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Try to display the processed image at each step and compare to the original.

after applying all preprocessing steps, here is `pytesseract.image_to_string` input image :

[image]

The first image is better then the processed.

My advice , Try the minimal amount of processing necessary to achieve your goal:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\tesseract\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

def ocr_core(img):
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

def get_grayscale(img):
    return cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


def remove_noise(img):
    return cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

def threshold(img):
    return cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

img = cv2.imread(r"/path/to/filename.jpg")

print(ocr_core(img))
```

Output :

```
 
Girl

n git letters on the ground glass of the door of room

INo. 962 were the words: "Robbins & Hartley, Brokers.”
The clerks had gone. It was past five. And with the so-
lid tramp of a drove of prize Percherons, scrub- women
were invading the cloud-capped twenty-story office bu
ding. A putt of red-hot air flavoured with lemon peelings,
soft-coal smoke and train oil came in through the halt-
open windows.

Robbins, fifty, something of an overweight beau. And.
addicted to first nights and hotel paim-rooms, pretended
to be envious of his partner's commuter’s joys.

“Going to be something doing in the humidity line to-
night,” he said. “Your out-of-town chaps will be the peo-
pple, with your katydids and moonlight and long drinks
and things out on the front porch.”

Hartley, twenty-nine, serious, thin, good-looking, ner-
vous, sighed and frowned a litle.

“Yes,” said he, ‘we always have cool nights in Floral-
hurst, especially in the winter:

‘Aman with an air of mystery came in the door and
‘went up to Hartley. “Ive found where she lives,” he an-
nounced in the portentous half-whisper that makes the
detective at work a marked being to his fellow men,

Hartley scowled him into a state of dramatic silence

-5-
```

Applying `get_grayscale`:

```
img = get_grayscale(img)
print(ocr_core(img))
```

Output :

```
Girl

n gilt letters on the ground glass of the door of room

INo. 962 were the words: "Robbins & Hartley, Brokers.”
The clerks had gone. It was past five. And with the so-
lid tramp of a drove of prize Percherons, scrub- women
were invading the cloud-capped twenty-story office buil-
ding. A putt of red-hot air flavoured with lemon peelings,
soft-coal smoke and train oil came in through the halt-
‘open windows.

Robbins, ftty, something of an overweight beau. And
addicted to first nights and hotel palm-rooms, pretended
to be envious of his partner's commuter’s joys.

“Going to be something doing in the humidity line to-
night,” he said. “Your out-of-town chaps will be the peo-
ple, with your katydids and moonlight and long drinks
and things out on the front porch.”

Hartley, twenty-nine, serious, thin, good-looking, ner-
vous, sighed and frowned a litle.

“Yes,” said he, "we always have coo! nights in Floral-
hurst, especially in the winter.

‘Aman with an air of mystery came in the door and
‘went up to Hartley. “Ive found where she lives,” he an-
nounced in the portentous half-whisper that makes the
detective at work a marked being to his fellow men,

Hartley scowled him into a state of dramatic silence

ag:
```